# WS02 HTTP header manipulation

Tags: rest, header, uri, wso2, wso2-esb

I would like to create a simple WS02 facade what offers a RESTful endpoint and forwards to a second RESTful (ie not SOAP) end point.  I would need to transform the endpoint address as well as add a version portion to the URI that will be obtained from the HTTP header of the original request.

How do I best do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the REST API functionality of WSO2 ESB.
You can find a sample for exposing a REST backend service over a different REST Api from the resource available at [1].

You can use REST_URL_POSTFIX property to add version portion dynamically to the endpoint URL.
Following is a sample config of setting REST_URL_POSTFIX property.

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/version/',$trp:HEADER_NAME_HERE)" scope="axis2"/>
```

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Using+the+REST+API#UsingtheRESTAPI-ExposingaBack-EndRESTServiceUsingaDifferentAPI